# Collapse vectors in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

I have an Rcpp function that gives me as result an list with some vectors of strings (std::vector).

```
 [[1]] [1] "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [[2]] [1] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"
 [[3]] [1] "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [[4]] [1] "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0"
```

I want to get these things like this:

```
[[1]] [1] "010000"
[[2]] [1] "000001" 
[[3]] [1] "010000"
[[4]] [1] "000100"
```

Now I am using: 
`apply(do.call(rbind,myFunctioninCPP(),1,paste0,collapse="")`
to get what I want.

I'm wondering if its possible to get this more "outofthebox" getting the result of myFunctioninCPP() in such way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Each vector of the list is a `std::vector<std::string>` type. And the output list doesn't has a fixed size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the following code which, for demonstration purposes, takes an ordinary `IntegerVector` as input. The use of `std::ostringstream` is rather straightforward and comes in handy when trying to perform operations like yours.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
String concat(IntegerVector x) {

  // convert intput to 'CharacterVector'
  int nChar = x.size();
  CharacterVector y = as<CharacterVector>(x);

  // initialize string output stream
  std::ostringstream ossOut;

  // concatenate input
  for (int i = 0; i < nChar; i++)
    ossOut << y[i];

  return ossOut.str();  
}
```

Now, load the function into R using `sourceCpp` and call it from inside an `*apply` loop.

```
## source c++ function
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("~/work/programming/concat.cpp")

## test run
lst <- list(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
            c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)) 

lapply(lst, concat)
[[1]]
[1] "010000"

[[2]]
[1] "000001"

[[3]]
[1] "010000"

[[4]]
[1] "000100"
```

Comment: Many Thanks! It works! :) I had to use only the final lines in my CPPfunction! :)   after the initialize string output stream

Comment: Glad to help. I included the first few lines of C++ code only for replication purposes. The main focus lies on `ostringstream`.