# Reverse a string on Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, string, reverse, rcpp

I'm trying to speed up some codes that I have in R using Rcpp. But I'm getting in trouble.

I have a vector that looks like:

```
vec
[1] "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa"
```

But for some **random** portion of my vector I want to reverse the string (Like `aA`). 
In my R Code I'm using `stringi::stri_reverse` which does what I want on a straightforward way. I tried to implement a similar approach on C++, but I'm in trouble! 
Basically, I'm trying to split each `vec[i]` to get `"A" "a"` and after that, use `std::reverse` and after that I'm concatenating using a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330439/collapse-vectors-in-rcpp). To get to that:

```
[1] "Aa" "aA" "aA" "aA" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa" "Aa"
```

I think this will not be faster (actually, might be pretty slower) than `stri_reverse` (which is a C function, I guess). What is the best way to accomplish that? Import `stringi::stri_reverse` to use on my Rcpp code? Copy the `stri_reverse` code (I don't know how yet, but I can figure it out) and put into my Rcpp function? I'm trying this for two days and I really appreciate any help from you guys.

Edit:

This is my Rcpp code till now (which I got it pretty much from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319858/slice-a-string-at-consecutive-indices-with-r-rcpp)):

```
CharacterVector stri_reverseC(String input, int n) {
  std::string myString = input;
  int cutpoint = n;
  int len = myString.length();
  int nout = len / cutpoint ;
  CharacterVector out( nout ) ;
  for( int i=0; i<nout; i++ ) {
    out[i] = myString.substr( cutpoint*i, 1 ) ;
  }

  std::reverse(out.begin(), out.end());
  out = concat(out);
  return out; 
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Rcpp function to your question?

Comment: What you are finding that one's own compiled code can end up being slower than some other (possibly more experienced) person's (possibly more tuned) code.  Nothing special about that.  Profiling tools can help.

Comment: @cmaher I edited and added my Rcpp function into my question. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the tip @DirkEddelbuettel (and what a honor!) I see what you mean and that is why I posted this. Should I import `stri_reverse` through `Rcpp::Function`? Or look (somehow) into its code and copy to my function? Or also build a function like I did above? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I still don't quite understand what your function is trying to do, but I would probably into standard `strings` (which have substring, reverse, collate, ...) or Boost strings for convenience.  This is no longer Rcpp specific and there are probably 100+ existing questions under `[c++]` you could look at.

Comment: I will definitely take a look on Boost and other questions under C++ tag. Thank you again @DirkEddelbuettel!